# I was trying to create a class but it seems like there is an error on every line

Tags: java

```
    package class_practice;

public class try1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String name1;
            int age1;
            Dog poodle;

            poodle= new Dog();
            name1="joe";
            poodle.setName1(name1);
            age1=9;
            poodle.setAge1(age1);
            System.out.println("dog's name is "+poodle.getName1());
            System.out.println("Dog's age is "+poodle.getage1());

        }
}

class Dog{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    name="j";
    age=0;
    public boolean setName1(String name1) {
        if (name.length()<1||name.length()>20)
            return false;
        name=name1;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean setAge1(int age1) {
        if(age1<0||age1>20)
            return false;
        age=age1;
        return true;
    }
    public String getName1() {
        return name;    
    }
    public int getage1() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

I don't get why it says there is an error on every line....
I was trying to practice creating my own class, and it was fine but when I wrote the int age, the errors started to pop up. I would fix it if I could understand what it meant, but the error explanations are very vague...

Comment: Show us the errors, please.

Comment: `if (name.length()<1||name.length()>20)` should be `if (name1.length()<1||name1.length()>20)`

Comment: In class `Dog` the lines `name="j";` and `age=0;` needs to be in a method, in a constructor, or on the same line as the declaration.  Those lines shouldn't "cause an error on every line" though so you'll have to be more specific about what errors you're actually seeing.

Comment: Just as an aside in your `main` method you have `name1="joe"; poodle.setName1(name1);`  You realize you could just pass the literal directly into a method parameter?  `poodle.setName( "Joe" );` works fine.  This isn't an error, just kind of odd to declare a variable just for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate a variable in different line in the class.

This does not work

```
 private String name;
    private int age;

    name="j";
    age=0;
```

this can be changed to

```
 private String name = "j";
    private int age = 0;
```